# Compare values from the same field in two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to put side by side two portions of a column in one table, having the the same description and a different "outer ID". Here is what the input table looks like:

```
+--+-------+-----------+
|ID|OUTERID|DESCRIPTION|
+--+-------+-----------+
|1 |1      |some desc 1|
+--+-------+-----------+
|2 |1      |some desc 2|
+--+-------+-----------+
|3 |1      |some desc 3|
+--+-------+-----------+
|4 |2      |some desc 2|
+--+-------+-----------+
|5 |2      |some desc 3|
+--+-------+-----------+
```

And here is what I'm trying to achieve from my select:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|DESCRIPTION_1|DESCRIPTION_2|
+-------------+-------------+
|some desc 1  |NULL         |
+-------------+-------------+
|some desc 2  |some desc 2  |
+-------------+-------------+
|some desc 3  |some desc 3  |
+-------------+-------------+
```

I tried with a simple JOIN, but as you can see I need to show the not matching values too.

```sql
SELECT a.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION_1,
       b.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION_2
  FROM My_Table a
  JOIN My_Table b on a.DESCRIPTION = b.DESCRIPTION
WHERE a.OUTERID = 1
  AND b.OUTERID = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with a full outer join:

```
SELECT a.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION_1,
       b.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION_2
FROM (SELECT a.*
      FROM My_Table a
      WHERE a.OUTERID = 1
     ) a FULL JOIN
     (SELECT b.*
      FROM My_Table b 
      WHERE b.OUTERID = 2
     ) b
     ON a.DESCRIPTION = b.DESCRIPTION;
```

Comment: So performance wise this is much better compared to a query from @YogeshSharma

Comment: @VishalSuthar . . . I am not sure.  You would have to test it.  Yogesh's query is also quite reasonable.  I offered this because it seemed closer to your original approach.

Answer (score 4):

You need `dense_rank()` & do conditional aggregation :

```
select max(case when OUTERID = 1 then DESCRIPTION  end) as DESCRIPTION_1,
       max(case when OUTERID = 2 then DESCRIPTION  end) as DESCRIPTION_2
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by DESCRIPTION) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by seq;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cte: (Though, I'm not sure why you would need to present both columns instead of just identify the 'dupes')

Table:

```
Create Table #tbl
(
ID Int,
OUTERID Int,
DESCRIPTION VarChar(20)
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
(1,1,'some desc 1'),
(2,1,'some desc 2'),
(3,1,'some desc 3'),
(4,2,'some desc 2'),
(5,2,'some desc 3')
```

CTE

```
With cte As
(
Select Description, Count(Distinct OuterID) As recs From #tbl
Group By Description
)
Select 
      Case When recs = 2 Or recs = 1 Then Description End As Description_1, 
      Case When recs = 2 Then Description End As Description_2
From cte
```